# How to read a RichText field?

Tags: lotusscript

I have an agent which is supposed to show a Notes DB as XML. I successfully retrieved all the fields but the RichText one. This is a code snippet:

```
Set session = New NotesSession
Set doc = session.DocumentContext
Set db = Session.CurrentDatabase
Set view = db.getview("myView")
Set doc = view.GetFirstDocument()

While Not(doc Is Nothing)
    Print "<job>"
    Print "<id>" & doc.id(0) & "</id>" ' Works fine since ID is a normal field
    Print "<text>" & doc.text(0) & "</text>" ' Does not work at all 
    Print "</job>"
    Set doc = view.GetNextDocument(doc)
Wend
```

If I use doc.text instead of doc.text(0) it only writes the first two words of the whole text. I suppose I have to cicle through the entire text but since I am new to Lotus Script I have no idea how to do it. Thank you guys.

EDIT: It turned out that Simon's answer is correct. The problem regards encoding as far as I can tell, if I remove the following Print:

```
Print |Content-Type:text/xml| & Chr$(13)
```

Everything works fine. I guess I need to define encoding in the header...

EDIT: I now use this Print instead:

```
Print "<text><![CDATA[" & rtitem.getUnformattedText() & "]]></text>"
```

However when I call the agent from the Browser it still broke at that print as it is ignoring the CDATA.

Comment: You should put that as a separate question instead of modifying your question each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the dot notation. To get the Richtext field you will need to use the getFirstItem() method call and link it to a NotesRichTextItem object. After that you should be able to convert it to text using the getUnformattedText() method.

```
Dim rtitem As NotesRichTextItem
...
rtitem = doc.getFirstItem("text")

Print "<text>" & rtitem.getUnformattedText() & "</text>"
```

Of course you may need to parse that text to prevent non standard characters in the XML, or wrap it in a CDATA block.

Comment: This actually returns only the first few words of the field. However every time I call the agent the result is different as it is reading a random row each time.

Comment: Thank you, I edited my question. Without CDATA how can I parse the text in Louts Script? Is there any library?

Comment: Midas LSX is the library you might want to look at.

Comment: And why not try the NotesDXLExporter class?

Comment: I was thinking to suggest that, but in this case they may only want a subset of data for another system and not the whole database. You could translate it from DXL via XLST, but that is even messier.